# What kind of function is represented by this graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

> What kind of function is represented by this graph?

I've created an example for this question:

[image: Graph]

For every $x$ I increase $y$ by $1$. But for every fourth $x$-value I increase $y$ by $2$ instead of $1$.
I wonder how I could describe this by a function.

Comment: Are the only valid values for $x, y$ integers?  Is the domain of the function (on which the function is defined)  $x\in [0, 8]$?  You need to fill such details.

Comment: You’ve already described this by a function, but I suppose that you’re looking for some closed-form formula.

Comment: Until this asker cares enough to comment and edit his/her post to clarify their post and to answer the questions folks have, I think users who try to "guess" what they mean and answer upon their interpretation, before the OP clarifies should not be rewarded. You really need to specify to in which set $x, y$ are elements.  The connecting the points given by $(x, y), x, y\in \mathbb Z$ isn't valid, unless $x, y$ can only be integers.

Answer (score 1):

$y(x) = x + \lfloor x/4 \rfloor$ for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But his graph is not discontinuous.

Comment: It seems that the function is defined only on the integers (square markers).  I'm willing to bet he plotted his function with a set of integers and just plotted the points joined.

Comment: Oh, perhaps so.

Comment: Indeed: what would it mean to determine "every fourth" real number, if $x, y \in \mathbb R$.  So this definition is correct, whereas the askers connecting the dots doesn't hold.

Comment: Good point.  Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a piecewise function.

$$1\le x\le 3 \implies f (x)=x $$

$$4\le x\le 7 \implies f (x)=x+1$$
$$f (8)=10$$

Comment: Ummm... so what about $x = 93.7$, for instance?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Our function is defined for $x\in [1,8] $ only. For x=93.7, you can take f (x)=-73.99999999999999.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima  We don't know that,  that it's range is $x \in [0, 8].$ You treat $x$ as though $x \in \mathbb R$, (rather, you never specify your domain).  What's the fourth value of $x \in [0, 8] \subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: Hmm... I don't remember saying that.  Oh, indeed I sleep!  I love my sleep-time.  But when I'm engaged in any activity, my brain "never sleeps", indeed, every moment in which I am physically awake, my brain is awake and focused!.